# Bestsellers not showing after enabling flat category and products

Tags: php, magento, flat

I have a code to show the best selling products in our store. The code works well if I disable flat category and flat product. Is there a way to make this work without disabling the flat product and category. Thanks...

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Viewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->setOrder(‘ordered_qty’, ‘desc’);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

        $products->setPageSize(15)->setCurPage(1);
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to show us some code? In addition, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That is more likely because `reports/product_collection` is only intended to be a collection used in adminhtml and does not implement the requirement to be loaded correctly when flat product/category is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that all of the product attributes you need to be returned by your query are marked as "Used in Product Listing"=YES in Magento admin (Catalog > Manage Attributes). Attributes only become part of the Flat table when this (or a few other) option is set, that's one of the main differences when having the flat catalog enabled.

You could Mage::log() the query for the collection select, and see what the differences are with flat catalog on and off, that would help you understand the differences and debug:

```
$products->setPageSize(15)->setCurPage(1);
$products->load(); // this is needed only for debugging, 
                   // to get the "real" database query
                   // PLEASE remove this and Mage::log 
                   // in production as it would affect performance
Mage::log( (string)$products->getSelect() );
$this->setProductCollection($products);
```